# Systematic error in counting values from CSV file

Tags: java, csv, parsing, arraylist, hashmap

I'm trying to grab values from a CSV file, where dataset looks something like:

===============================
========Begin File ============
CompanyA,toola
CompanyA,toolb
.....
.....
....
....
CompanyB,toola
CompanyB,toolc
....
....
...
CompanyN,tooln

======================

I approached this problem by using a BufferedReader object in order to read in each line of the file, then I created a string array for the line, which was split with a comma. Afterwards, I assigned respective variables for the company and tool names buy indexing the string array of the line being read. Each tool and company name pairing in the line is stored in HashMap. the code is as follows:

```
    public void run() {

    String csvFile = "/Users/zzzOp/Downloads/companies.csv";
    BufferedReader br1 = null;
    BufferedReader br2 = null;
    BufferedReader br3 = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";

    try {
        //Create BufferedReader object
        br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        br3 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));


        //Generate User ArrayList for all tools and store in map
        while ((line = br1.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] inLine = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
            String toolName;
            toolName = inLine[1];
            userMap.put(toolName, new ArrayList<String>());             
        }

        //Map tools with user lists
        while ((line = br2.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] array = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
            String companyName, toolName;
            companyName = array[0];
            toolName = array[1];
            tmpTool.add(toolName);
            tmpCmp.add(companyName);
            if (userMap.keySet().contains(toolName)) {
                userMap.get(toolName).add(companyName);
            } 
        }

        //Test for debugging
        System.out.println(userMap.get("Dropbox").size());
        System.out.println(userMap.get("Salesforce").size());  

........
..some code.....
........
.....
....
```

In the two test cases above, I get values of 182 and 84 for Dropbox and Salesforce users respectively. However when I use Excel to count, the values I get for Dropbox and Salesforce users are 184 and 85.

The fundamental problem in taking the wrong counts is that my end goal for this data is to calculate the probability p that someone is using tool X, given that they also use tool Y. This throws off my calculations in the latter part of the script where this occurs. Nonetheless, I need to calculate the right values for the amount of users. Otherwise, my denominator will always be off.

I'm quite confused and feel as if I have exhausted my efforts. I think I'm reading in the file correctly yet the counts are wrong. I have no idea why the counts aren't matching! I appreciate all forms of help, thank you.

Comment: Hard to tell from incomplete code listing. A suggestion though,  you should open your csv file once and combine all your BufferedReader loop into 1 since they all process same set of data.

Comment: The only time I actually reference the userMap variable is in the beginning of the program, where I declare my instance variables. I'm not exactly sure if that helps?

Comment: How did  you do the count in excel? D is you use macro or excel functions? Or manual sort & select? Have you verified the csv data that there are no extra space in some of the name, eggs "Dropbox" vs "Dropbox "

Comment: I used the countif command to math each string. The data itself is clean.